# Power shell new line in email body

Tags: powershell

I have currently this script and it works fine :

```
    $Path = "C:\test\log\trace.log"
Write-Output "before delete"> $Path 
(Get-ChildItem "C:\TestMail\test\test1" -Recurse | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname) >> $Path  
(Get-ChildItem "C:\TestMail\test\test1" -Recurse | 
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).addDays(-1)} |
    Remove-Item -Force) >> $Path
Write-Output "preserved"  >> $Path
(Get-ChildItem "C:\TestMail\test\test1" -Recurse | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname) >> $Path
$body = Get-Content -Path $PATH -Raw
```

Problem is that i receive single string results in body when im using Send-MailMessage in power shell.

How to get new lines for each string that i receive in body?

Thanks!

Comment: `$body = $body -replace '\r?\n','<br />'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Please could you give me more details? Im not familiar that much in Power shell so where do i need to put this exactly? I need to include $PATH as well

Comment: It will replace the newlines in the file with `<br />` (html line breaks)

Answer (score 2):

Ive did it!

```
$body =  Get-Content $Path |%{ "$_`n" }|Out-String
```

I put this and send it as regular  -body  $body via Send-MailMessage